# Se puede poner el IDE de Genexus en Modo Dark o en otros temas? El color blanco me perturba la vista

Tags: genexus, ide, theme

He intentado buscar respuestas pero lo único que encontré en la Wiki es como hacer un dark mode para un web panel. Me gustaría saber si en Gx 17 o alguno tiene la opción de cambiar el tema del IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes la posibilidad de cambiar el "style" pero no pasarlo a DarkMode.
Ejecutando genexus.exe /IDEStyle:blue por ejemplo.

Más información https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6740,GeneXus%20command%20line%20parameters